# Включение в архив файлов, имена которых начинаются с точки

Tags: shell, tar

Необходимо создать архив по *SSH* на удаленном сервере.

Стандартная команда *tar* не включает в архив файлы *.htaccess*:

```
tar -czvf archname.tar.gz *
```

Как сделать, чтобы в архив были включены все без исключения файлы, **в том числе и .htaccess**?

Comment: Может так?

    tar -czvf archname.tar.gz ./

Comment: Нет, мне нужно создать архив только текущей директории (той, в которой я в данный момент нахожусь). Насколько я понимаю, ./ отправить меня в корень, разрешенного правами SSH, каталога.

Comment: @Alexey Nechesanov, ./ это **текущая директория**. 

Учите матчасть.

Comment: @avp ну работает он через ssh. И tar вызывает в сессии ssh.

Да, ещё. Я не знаком с тем, какие хостингом предоставляются права. Доступ к /tmp у него обязательно должен быть?

Comment: Пусть проверит. А для tar-а все равно, как его вызвали (telnet, ssh ...).

Comment: @avp у меня включает.

Answer (score 2):

квантификатор `*` совпадёт со всеми именами файлов и каталогов в текущем каталоге **кроме** тех, которые начинаются с точки.

чтобы включить и файлы/каталоги, начинающиеся с точки, можно указать не «все файлы/каталоги» (`*`) а просто «текущий каталог» — `.`

пример:

```
$ touch file .file
$ tar -czvf archname.tar.gz .
./
./.file
./file
tar: .: file changed as we read it
```

как видим, в архив включены и `file` и `.file`. последняя строчка с предупреждением о том, что *каталожный файл* изменился в процессе выполнения программы `tar`, вызвана тем, что файл с архивом мы создаём **тоже** в текущем каталоге. а подобное действие вызывает изменения в *каталожном файле* (по простому говоря — изменения содержимого каталога и его свойств — времени доступа и модификации).

---

**альтернативный вариант**

возможно, вам может не подойти предложенный вариант, например, потому, что в архивированных файлах/каталогах появится ещё один дополнительный элемент пути (`./`).

в таком случае вы можете просто дописать к используемой вами команде файлы/каталоги, начинающиеся с точки. примерно так:

```
$ touch file .file
$ tar -czvf archname.tar.gz * .file 
file
.file
```

Answer (score -1):

При архивировании tar включает все, что вы указываете ему.
В противном случае, он не может запаковать файлы, которые нельзя ему даже прочитать, т.е. команда архива выполняется с правами "слабого" юзера. Из этого вывод: что-либо дать читать этот файл либо запускать процесс из под другого пользователя.

**//upd**

> Да, но это банальный виртуальный хостинг. Я не могу ничего запустить 
> с правами root.

Виртуальный хостинг или сервер? Яснее нужно выражаться.

> А изменять CMOD на .htaccess - это грозит не самыми >лучшими последствиями.

Это никому ничего не грозит!

*Да, кстати, от прав в принципе не зависит.*

Вообще тогда интересно, что за Ось стоит на хостинге, и хостинг ли это или все таки вирт сервер?

Comment: Да, но это банальный виртуальный хостинг. Я не могу ничего запустить с правами root. А изменять CMOD на .htaccess - это грозит не самыми лучшими последствиями.

Comment: @Alexey Nechesanov, мне кажется .htaccess у Вас не попадал в архив **не из-за прав**, а потому, что он с '.' начинается. 

Символ '*' в tar -czvf archname.tar.gz \* просто 
не сопоставляется (это в sh такие правила) с именами, которые начинаются с точки.

Использование ./ вместо \* должно решать проблему.

Comment: avp, спасибо. Принял. Буду пробовать. О результатах отпишусь.